# SQL log in from Cron job

Tags: sql, oracle, cron, sqlplus

On RHEL 7, I am trying to access a SQL table. When I run the code from terminal I can access the database and the script runs as expected. When I run the same script from crontab I get an error:

```
Error 6 initializing SQL*Plus
SP2-0667: Message file sp1<lang>.msb not found
SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory
```

Here is my code:

```
getSequence()
{
    SQLPLUS=/oracle/app/oracle/product/12c/bin/sqlplus
    seq_num=$($SQLPLUS -S $OPS_DB_USER/$OPS_DB_ORACLE_PASSWD<<-EOF
    set heading off
    set feedback off
    select Sequence.nextval from dual;
    EOF)
    VERSION=`printf "%07d" $seq_num`
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory?

Comment: I have tried export ORACLE_HOME=/oracle/app/oracle/product/12c/bin from within the script.

Comment: try ORACLE_HOME=/oracle/app/oracle/product/12c  (exclude /bin) as it wants the HOME directory and not the BIN directory

Comment: Thanks, that was definitely part of it.

Answer (score 0):

If the script runs as expected. Make sure the permissions are set correctly on the script so when the cron runs it has the correct permissions to execute the script. Double check your environment variables as well. Here is an example of how I call a proc using a bash script. Hope this helps.

```
#!/bin/bash

sqlplus -s <<%%
$DBLOG/$DBPWD@$ORACLE_SID

exec "my_proc"();

exit
%%
```